# Updating Object Properties from inside an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I know this is all basic stuff but it's all new to me so any help would be great. I'm trying to make a function that updates object properties, where the objects are all inside of an array. This is homework for my bootcamp I'm taking and this is what I got so far. I know the return needs to be outside of the loops scope, but I'm more hung up on the proper notation for the conditional statement and accessing and manipulating the object keys inside the array.

```js
function findObject(array, key, target) {
  //look through the array by creating a for loop

  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

    //set conditional to check if an object in array has target value on its key prop

    if (array[i].key === target) {

      //if the above condition is met, return that object
      return array[i];
    }

  } //if its not return null
  return null;
}
```

> Prompt:3. Implement the function, findObject.
> Its parameters are:
>
> One Array called array
> array is filled with Objects
> One String called key
> One String called target
>
> Look through array and return the object that has the target value on its key property
>
> Return null if target is not found

Comment: Are you sure the `key` is being passed into the `findObject` function ? I think you'll not have that .

Comment: yes, the, question in posed like this in the code editor

Comment: function findObject(array, key, target){

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems key is a string which value is the name of the property/key that you wanted to search. Please check whether following code works for or not.

```js
function findObject(array, key, target) {
let foundObj=null;
  //look through the array by creating a for loop

  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

    //set conditional to check if an object in array has target value on its key prop

    if (array[i][key] === target) {

      //if the above condition is met, return that object
      foundObj=array[i];
      break;
    }

  } //if its not return null
  return foundObj;
}
console.log(findObject([{name:"usa",id:"usa"},{name:"uk",id:"uk"}],"name","usa"));
```

Comment: No, it didn't like that...I've tried a few similar iterations like that, creating a variable assigned to an empty array and pushing the array[i][key] into it...with no luck

Comment: @MichaelJarrett I have given an example in the code to call findObject function. Please check.